# Can jconsole data be retrieved from the command line?

Tags: java, performance, command-line, monitoring, jconsole

I am currently using `jconsole` to monitor performance metrics of my Java application and would like to **script** this **data acquisition**.

Is there a way to retrieve these VM metrics (heap memory usage, thread count, CPU usage etc.) to `STDOUT`?
The data in `top -p PID -b -n 1` doesn't quite cut it.

Thanks

Comment: There are other/similar options mentioned in this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/q/1751130/6563567

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`jconsole` just provides a wrapper around the JMX MBeans that are in the platform `MBeanServer`.

You can write a program to connect to your VM using the [Attach API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html) which would then query the MBeans.

Or you can expose the platform `MBeanServer` over RMI and query the MBeans that way.

See the [java.lang.management](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html) package for more info

Answer (score 12):

Maybe [jvmtop](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop) is worth a look.
It's a command-line tool which provides a **live-view** for several metrics.

#### Example output of the VM overview mode:

```
 JvmTop 0.4.1  amd64  8 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-27, load avg 0.12
 http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

  PID MAIN-CLASS      HPCUR HPMAX NHCUR NHMAX    CPU     GC    VM USERNAME   #T DL
 3370 rapperSimpleApp  165m  455m  109m  176m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        21
11272 ver.resin.Resin [ERROR: Could not attach to VM]
27338 WatchdogManager   11m   28m   23m  130m  0.00%  0.00% S6U37 web        31
19187 m.jvmtop.JvmTop   20m 3544m   13m  130m  0.93%  0.47% S6U37 web        20
16733 artup.Bootstrap  159m  455m  166m  304m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        46
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this jmx query tool by command line: http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [`jmap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html), which can be used to take a heap dump from the console.

For data not covered in the heap dump, I believe `jconsole` just uses JMX to connect to the running JVM to get statistics - so it's likely possible to create your own application which could pull those same types of stats from JMX.

Answer (score 6):

Some other useful CLI tools to monitor a Java applications are:

- [Jmxterm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm) which gives full access to all MBeans on the application server, runs interactively or not,
- [jmxbox](https://github.com/jeanarcand/jmxbox) which can only connect through a TCP socket, not directly to a local process with its PID

Answer (score 4):

You might find [jvm-mon](https://github.com/ajermakovics/jvm-mon) useful for this. It is a JVM monitoring tool for the command line that disaplys:

- jvm processes
- cpu and GC usage
- heap usage and size
- top threads

The metrics and charts update while the tool is open.

Sample: [image: jvm-mon]

Comment: Any tool like  ```jvm-mon```  for monitoring java-17 applications from command line terminal/console?

Answer (score 2):

[jstack](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) offers a number of useful bits of information in its normal output. Heap memory usage is directly available, broken down by GC region; thread count could be determined with a little bit of perl / grep / etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer to your question:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xloggc:logs\gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the tomcat jmxproxy for access from scripts ( http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet ).

I haven't used any of them but one of the jmx-rest projects might be an option for a non-tomcat server ( http://www.google.com/search?q=jmx+rest ).