# Starting and reconnecting to a spring bean from console

Tags: java, spring, console

I like to write a little server application being controlled by a little console app (start, pause, stop, etc). For the server spring should be used (part of it already exist). So what I do to start the server is something like this:

1. start a server thread and exit main method

and then, in the thread:

1. load application context from xml
2. start some worker threads connecting to beans doing stuff

Now I want the server to be stopped by another command. How can I connect to the already running context and shut it down?

Thanks for your help, 
Alexander

Comment: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/216.html just add spring part into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical way to manage running Java code is through [JMX](http://java.sun.com/products/JavaManagement/).
Spring lets you [export beans as MBeans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-exporting).

And for accessing JMX via the command line, look at the answers to this recent question:

> **[Calling JMX MBean method from a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751130/calling-jmx-mbean-method-from-a-shell-script)**

Comment: I tried it with MBeans and got it working. I also refactored the server code itself into a beanm which calls the close method on its own context when its close method is called. Works for now. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pid file, when the server starts, it should log the pid to a file, server.pid. When you do a stop, you can read the process and kill it. Or even simpler, have a ever running thread in your main class which keeps looking for a file in some folder. As soon as the file becomes available or gets modified, it will stop the server.