# too many http sessions with grails and memcached-session-store

Tags: grails, memcached, monitoring, spymemcached

I am a litle bit lost here.

I am using a grails application deployed in tomcat with [memcached-session-store](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/). That it uses [spymemcached](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/).

I am also using [melody plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/grails-melody) to monitor the app.

In the righter-upper part, there is a http-sessions graph that only grows.

We need to know if this is a potential problem. For now, and without know, we daily restart the webservers. And as a last test we are going to let the http-sessions grows to see if in the future it tends to clean it self.

This is the graph that I am talking about:

[image: too many Http sessions]

So: is a problem? Do I have to configure memcached, tomcat, grails, memcached-session-store or spymemcached to expirate the sessions with a less expiration time? I couldn't find in Interet how to do that.

Any pointer would help.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

AFAICS there were 117 concurrent sessions at max, which are not too many generally. You can also limit the maximum number of active sessions in your context.xml/server.xml via maxActiveSessions for the manager btw.

Some questions:

- Do you experience any issues (e.g. running out of memory or anything else)?
- How much memory is available to your jvm?
- How much memory is used by the jvm?
- Do you know how many sessions your app can handle?
- What's your session expiration?
- What's the size of your (serialized) sessions? You can e.g. check jmx stats from memcached-session-manager (see [JMXStatistics](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/wiki/JMXStatistics)).

Finally I'd say that you should keep your tomcats up and running until you experience any real problem.

Comment: Thanks for the several pointers. There is no issues till now. The memory it seems stable. The session expiration (in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml) is 10 minutes. I read the section with JMXStatistics but I don't know how to query them by console (the only way I can access the webservers). Do you know how? regards

Comment: @damian Good to hear that there are no issues. Regarding jmx, what about http://code.google.com/p/jminix/ (haven't tried it by myself)? This one provides also useful links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751130/calling-jmx-mbean-method-from-a-shell-script