# Linux Shell Script for calling JBoss 5x JMX's MBeans

Tags: shell, jmx, jboss5.x, mbeans

I want to call JBoss 5x JMX's mbeans with linux shell script. Is there anyway to call JBoss 5x JMX's mbeans with Linux shell script?

Comment: Duplicate as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751130/calling-jmx-mbean-method-from-a-shell-script

Comment: @Ted I already seen this, but it is not similar as I want. If you are experienced on this, could you support some simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jboss shipped with twiddle script, you can get the list of Mbeans from jmx-console and query/invoke it through twiddle, such as

```
$JBOSS_HOME/twiddle.sh -s 127.0.0.1 invoke "jboss.system:type=ServerInfo" listMemoryPools "True"  
$JBOSS_HOME/twiddle.sh -s 127.0.0.1 get "jboss.system:type=ServerInfo"
```

and you can also use [nagios-jmx-plugin](http://snippets.syabru.ch/nagios-jmx-plugin/usage.html)

```
java -jar check_jmx.jar -U service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/jmxconnector --username admin --password admin -O "jboss.system:type=ServerInfo" -A FreeMemory
```

Comment: The first way is OK for me but how i access this on other machine not localhost.Please share me this.

Comment: add -u username -p password and change -s to real hostname    $JBOSS_HOME/twiddle.sh -u admin -p admin -s otherhost.com get "jboss.system:type=ServerInfo"

Answer (score 0):

Only by writing a Java program to invoke from the shell script to talk to the MBeans.