# Clear ehcache of remote server

Tags: java, ehcache

How can we clear `ehcache` on a remote server?

My application is running in staging environment (host `111.22.3.44` and port `17000`) and I want to write an utility method that can connect to a given `host:port` and clear the `ehcache` of my App. This utility should to work in Windows as well as Linux.

I use `JConsole.exe` utility to flush the cache of `ehcache` created in stage-server, but there is a situation where I need to do it programatically.

Comment: looks like you need some method of calling remote jxm bean. start looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751130/calling-jmx-mbean-method-from-a-shell-script

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I went through specified url but I have following doubts because I need to implement it in Java, In my case what will be the url (111.22.3.45) and what will be the bean name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hurrey...:) I got the solution for clearing `ehcache` on a remote environment. Here, I have written a Java utility method that will flush out `ehcache` of a given remote machine that is specified by host name and port.

```
public void flushEhcache() throws IOException, NamingException,  MalformedObjectNameException, NullPointerException, AttributeNotFoundException, InstanceNotFoundException, MBeanException, ReflectionException {
    String host = "111.22.3.44";
    String port = "16000";
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://"
        + host + ":" + port + "/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
    MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();        
    ObjectName beanName = new ObjectName("net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=Your  Application Name Here");        
    mbsc.invoke(beanName, "clearAll", new Object[0], new String[0]);
    System.out.println("Flushed out ehcache succesfully");
}
```

Comment: If you are unsure of what ObjectName to use. It's easy to connect and get the names of all existing MBeans, like this: `Set<ObjectName> names = mbsc.queryNames(null, null);`