# How to redeliver messages from a DLQ in the ActiveMQ command-line?

Tags: activemq-classic, command-line-interface, messaging, administration, jolokia

I'm searching for the way to retry some messages from the DLQ via command-line tool. Quick look at `activemq-admin` tool doesn't give me an answer for that.

I have a selector, list of messages in the DLQ and want to retry them one more time. I know, that from the admin web interface it's possible to select a one message or several and retry them, but for security reasons we don't use Jolokia.

Answer (score 1):

The redeliver feature is a JMX feature, so if you have jolokia turned off, I guess the same goes for remote JMX. If you have local JMX turned on, you can use jconsole or similar to do redeliver - that is, if you can log in with GUI.

The command line tool that comes with ActiveMQ is not really up to the task. You can find a [bunch of online tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751130/calling-jmx-mbean-method-from-a-shell-script) to access JMX from command line, but you probably want to make some script for it then.

If you want remote access and can only use the transport protocol (openwire or AMQP), you can use the ["A" tool](https://github.com/northlander/a). It can move messages using selectors and similar tasks. It's handy, but then I wrote it, so I'm a bit biased.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Looks like there is no simple way to do this from the box. It's a pity, that built-in tool doesn't have an API for that. Will wait for some answers for several days, maybe we miss something...

Comment: I guess the "built-in tool" i considered to be JMX/Jolokia which can be used remote (with SSL/credentials security). But I agree, sometimes, a command line tool from the local box could be useful