# Can I query jmx port using curl to check that jmx is working fine?

Tags: chef-infra, jmx, inspec

Is it possible to query some/any data from the jmx port using curl? I am writing an inspec(chef) test to check that jmx is working fine.

```
# curl https://localhost:9114
curl: (35) Encountered end of file

# curl -s -w "%{http_code}\n" https://localhost:9114 -o /dev/null
000
```

Simply doing curl doesn't return anything useful.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

from what i understand, you would like to check whether jmx is working; this has nothing to do with chef. at the time of writing, inspec does not have a [builtin resource](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/) for testing jmx.

consider the following approaches for testing jmx:

1. use a [non-interactive command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751426/1184717) (not jconsole or any gui) client to jmx. for instance, see [`jmxterm`](https://github.com/jiaqi/jmxterm/wiki)` and query the jmx as you need
2. sample the [jmx metric](https://developer.bring.com/blog/measuring-jvm-stats/) and analyze it. for instance, did it pass a certain threshold

Comment: I don't have jmxterm in my docker container but curl is available.