# How to collect JVM performance statistics from java

Tags: java, junit, jvm, performance-testing

I want to write a JUnit testcase that will also be able to monitor and collect the parameters of a JVM, like the memory usage, heap size and other custom JMX managed beans etc. I will be having the JMX address of the JVM. More clearly, I would like to know if I could gather the information that jconsole provides but programatically without a UI. And then I would want to check if the JVM performance has degraded or not by integrating it with Jenkins. Are there any already available tools that do this?

Comment: I think I found a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193954/can-jconsole-data-be-retrieved-from-the-command-line). I am yet to analyze the tools that are mentioned there though.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Virtual Machine Agent, here is a good [educational article](https://blogs.oracle.com/kto/entry/using_vm_agents)

Also you can use `Profiler` tools in eclipse to monitor your program performance

Comment: I would want to automate these tests. I will be running these tests through ant. Though I could use eclipse for initial debugging, that isn't what I want to achieve. I will check the usage of Virtual Machine Agent. The article was written in 2005. Hope it still serves good.

Comment: The website is longer available :(