# GET Tomcat java maximum memory pool size using cmd or PowerShell

Tags: java, powershell, tomcat7, tomcat6, tomcat8

i have several Tomcat 6,7,8 servers and i would like to run a PowerShell script to get me the Maximum memory pool size of its JAVA Jvm options, is there a way to get it ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jvmtop](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop). It is a command line tool to fetch information from locally running JVM's.

If you have remote servers then you probably need to active JMX on the servers and write your own code. See [Can jconsole data be retrieved from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193954/can-jconsole-data-be-retrieved-from-the-command-line)

Comment: no other ways to interact with the java  ? something like 
javaw.exe -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "MaxHeapSize"
but for the maximum memory pool