# Can i see the JVM specific configurations in command prompt?

Tags: java, jvm

Is there any way to see all available configurations like memory used, heap size, stack etc.. of JVM in command propmt.?

Comment: What you actually set at start time or all the options available? All options you get from the Oracle help pages.

Comment: hmmm you can start from `java -h` and `man java` I suppose :) also have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html

Comment: Do you want to know what you can set? Or what configuration a running JVM is operating under?

Comment: also "all availabe configurations" is a broad statement, could you narrow it down to what you really are interested in

Comment: A number of tools & techniques have been mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193954/can-jconsole-data-be-retrieved-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it myself yet. But this tool looks very promising

https://github.com/ajermakovics/jvm-mon

Internally it is using jvmtop (https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop) but adds some nice dashboard style to it. It basically depends on your exact needs what to use.

Answer (score 1):

JDK built-in [`jstat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html) and [`jcmd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) utilities can show almost all JVM metrics.

For example, the following command will print more than 200 counters of all JVM subsystems (GC, JIT compiler, Runtime etc.):

```
jcmd <PID> PerfCounter.print
```